Why am i not seeing the import library option in Eclipse, i have added the required library in the build config path
`
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Testfile</groupId>
  <artifactId>Testfile</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  
 <dependencies> 
     <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.16.1</version>
</dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.8.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.5</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.21.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.20.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>7.10.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.20.0</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>

`
Appreciate any help on the above mentioned?
Adding the snapshot here
I am trying to import the library on hovering the mouse for the Java selenium keywords. and the libraries to get imported in my java class file by default , but i am unable to do this.

In the Package Explorer two system libraries are shown for your Testfile project, JRE System Library JavaSE-1.8] and JRE System Library [jre]. Two two system libraries are wrong. It looks like you edited the Java Build Path manually instead of editing the pom.xml file of your Maven project. Please do the following: right-click on the project folder and choose _Maven > Update Project...and if this does not help show yourpom.xmlfile (add the content of it as text to your question formatted as _Sample Code_: indented by four spaces to keep line breaks and characters like<`).

Please find the added POM XML ,  Ihave removed the JRE System Library [jre] from the build library path

In your POM, specify the Java version. And then right-click your project and choose Maven > Update Project... to revert your manually changes you did in the Java Build Path which was a mistake.

The below Selenium Java atrifact already specified. Which other artifact id of Java needed ?

org.seleniumhq.selenium
selenium-java
4.21.0


In your POM, you might want to specify the Java version you want to use in your project: before <dependencies> add something like <properties><maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source><maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target></properties> (if JRE System Library JavaSE-1.8] is correct, it would be 1.8 or 8 instead of 17).


1.8
1.8
 -- The import library not displaying even after this. Performed the steps as mentioned above.
Which dependency contains the ExpectedConditions class? Does the Package Explorer still shows the two system libraries, JRE System Library JavaSE-1.8] and JRE System Library [jre]?

It worked when I added a new class under a different project folder, as I was getting this error under a specific project alone. I will start working from the new folder for now. Not sure why for that particular project folder I was not able to import library

Your project seems to be using Maven as the build system, from the little that we can see in the screenshot. In that case you should specify all needed libraries as Maven dependencies in the pom.xml file and don't touch Eclipse build path at all. Basically Maven replaces the IDE build system. If you edit the build path manually it will produce inconsistent results. With Maven it should produce the same result in the command line or in the IDE.
